# Running BlogEngine.NET with ASP.NET MVC under same website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, blogengine.net

Can anyone please help me with this? 
I have a Windows 2008 server and MVC 2.0 site is hosted under IIS 7.0 root directory. The site works fine. I want to use the BlogEngine.NET with my site. For example if my mite name is http:// mysite.com (which is the root of IIS) and the blog should be http://mysite.com/blog/Default.aspx

Is this possible? Can I create a sub virtual directory within my root (where the MVC 2 app is hosted) and run the ASP.NET BlogEngine.Net in it?

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I feel that would be much more better blog.mysite.com. Using a subdomain instead of a subfolder.

Comment: Exaclty correct and I agree with you. I managed to get it working the way you mentioned above - Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did decide to go with a single web application, you may find the following links useful:

http://redditech.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/howto-convert-blogenginenet-from-web-site-to-web-application-project/

http://www.upfromthesky.com/blog/post/2009/01/30/Integrate-BlogEngine-145-into-an-exisitng-website-%28VSNET-Website-Project%29.aspx

I've currently got a blog running at mysite.com/blog - it seems to be working fine, I'm just in the process of consolidating the membershipservices to work with my existing credentials.

There are important comments on the first link that you will probably need to do to get extensions working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Cut off the /blog app from MVC app using

```
<clear />
```

under

```
<system.web><pages><namespaces><clear />
```

For more details check this link.

http://www.dondraper.com/2010/02/how-to-stop-inheritance-of-webconfig-files/